# Custom Validator for Static Use of Reflection vs. Custom Rule in SonarQube (Java, Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, validation, reflection, sonarqube

There may be some related questions, but I think my situation is peculiar enough to justify a question on its own.

I'm working on a historically grown huge Java project (far over one million LOC, due to other reasons we're still bound to Java 6 at the moment), where reflection is used to display data in tables - reflection is not used for dynamically changing the displayed data, but just for using some kind of short cuts in the code. A simplified part of the code looks like this.

```
TableColumns taco = new TableColumns(Bean.class);
taco.add(new TableColumn("myFirstMember"));
taco.add(new TableColumn("mySecondMember"));
 ...
List<Bean> dataList = getDataFromDB(myFilterSettings);
taco.displayTable(dataList);
```

So the values of the table cells of each row are stored in an instance of `Bean`. The values for the first cell comes from calling `itemOfDataList.getMyFirstMember()` (so here comes the reflection part of the code). The rendering of the table cells is done depending on the return type of the `itemOfDataList.getMyFirstMember()`.

This way, it's easy to add new columns to the table, getting them rendered in a standard way without caring about any details.

Problem of this approach: when the getter name changes, the compiler doesn't notice and there will be an exception at runtime in case `Bean.getMyFirstMember()` was renamed to `Bean.getMyFirstMemberChanged()`.

While reflection is used to determine which getter is called, the needed info is in fact available at compile time, there are no variables used for the column info.

**My goal:** having a validator that will check at compile time whether the needed getter methods in the `Bean` class do exist.

**Possible solultions:**

- **modifying the code** (using more specific infos, writing an adapter, using annotations or whatever that can be checked at compile time by the compiler), **I explicitely don't want a solution of this kind**, due to the huge code basis. I just need to guarantee that the reflection won't fail at runtime.
- writing a **custom validator**: I guess this shouldn't be too complex, but I have no real idea how to start, we use eclipse as ide, so it should be possible to write such a custom validator - any hints for a good starting point?
  The validator should show a warning in eclipse if the `parameter` in the `TableColumn(parameter)` isn't `final` (should be a literal or constant). The validator should show an error in eclipse if the `TableColumn` is added to `TableColumns` and the corresponding `Bean.getParameter()` doesn't exist.
- as we use **SonarQube** for quality checking, we could also implement a **custom rule** checking if the methods do exist - not completely sure if such a custom rule is possible (probably yes)
- maybe other solutions that will give a fast feedback within eclipse that some tables won't render correctly after some getter methods were renamed

**What I'm asking for:**

- what will be easier in this situation: writing a custom validator for eclipse or writing a custom rule for SonarQube?
- hints where to start either approach
- hints for other solultions

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives:

1. You could migrate to more modern Java for this pattern, it is a prime candidate for method references. Then, your IDE of choice can automatically take care of the problem when you refactor/rename. This can be done bit-by-bit as the opportunity/necessity arises.
2. You could write your own custom annotations:

   - Which you can probably get SonarQube to scan for
   - Which could allow you to take advantage of javax.validation.* goodies, so your code may look/feel more like 'standard' Java EE code.
   - Annotations can be covered by a processor during the build step, various build tools have ways to hook this up -- and the processor can do more advanced/costly introspection so you can push the validation to compile-time as opposed to run-time.

Comment: I think Method References came with Java 8? The project is still bound to Java 6 for reasons to complex to explain here in 500 characters. Adding annotations will also require hundreds of hours due to the huge code base. Therefore I was asking how to write a validator or custom rule for this specific situation without bothering to change the code. When the project is migrated to Java 8 maybe in 10 years, we can rethink using Method References then.